# PHP encode/decode string only numbers and characters

Tags: php, hash, encoding, decode, encode

I know about the PHP function encode() and decode(), they work well for me, but I want to pass the encoded string inside an url, but encode does return special chars like "=" "," "'" etc....

This does obviously break my script, what would be the best way to encode a string and get only numbers and characters?

Should I use a special hash?

Comment: [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also a [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) method that respects special characters.

Furthermore, [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) and [`rawurldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) are provided to encode according to [RFC-3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986). This will return a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

Try urlencode()

This should encode the encoded string in a way that you can safely pass it in an url.

Comment: First encode the string the way you want it, then pass it through urlencode() to get an URL-suitable string. That string can then be passed through an URL.